# How to take screenshot of webview part only using Appium

Tags: android, webview, automated-tests, appium, screenshot

I want to take a screenshot of Webview part only inside a hybrid android app using appium.

I used the following code to take screenshot.

```
    String Screenshotpath = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/";
    System.out.println(Screenshotpath);
    File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot) driver)
            .getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
    System.out.println(scrFile); 
    try {
        FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File(Screenshotpath
                + "screenshotwebview" + ".jpg"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

It works fine and takes a screenshot of the whole screen. But when I try to set context to webview and try to take screenshot using the above code it shows the following error

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command.
```

`Original error: Could not proxy. Proxy error: Could not proxy command to remote server.`

`Original error: Error: ESOCKETTIMEDOUT (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information) Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds`

Is it possible to take the screenshot of the webview part only using the Appium ?

Can any one please help

Comment: Could you check my answer ?

Answer (score 0):

And you can do like this.

Before doing it ,you can do this.

```
    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setSupportZoom(true); 
    webView.requestFocusFromTouch();
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    });
    webView.loadUrl("your url");
```

And check version.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    checkSdkVersion();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_webview_capture);
}

// check version
private void checkSdkVersion() {
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        WebView.enableSlowWholeDocumentDraw();
    }
}
```

Add permission in your manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

**Way 1**

```
private void getScreenshot() {
    float scale = webView.getScale();
    int webViewHeight = (int) (webView.getContentHeight() * scale + 0.5);
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(webView.getWidth(), webViewHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    webView.draw(canvas);
    // save to the File
    try {
        String fileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/webview_capture1.jpg";
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
        // Save
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 70, fos);
        fos.close();
        Toast.makeText(WebviewFromDraw.this, "Screenshot OK", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        bitmap.recycle();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.getMessage();
    }
}
```

**Way 2**

```
private void getScreenshot() {
    Picture picture = webView.capturePicture();
    int width = picture.getWidth();
    int height = picture.getHeight();
    if (width > 0 && height > 0) {
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        picture.draw(canvas);
        try {
            String fileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/webview_capture3.jpg";
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 70, fos);
            fos.close();
            Toast.makeText(WebviewFromCapture.this, "Screenshot ok", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            bitmap.recycle();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```